# Nuevo en MVVM Duda con inotifypropertychanged

Tags: wpf

Tengo una duda; ¿Cómo implementar correctamente el patrón MVVM?

Tengo un modelo; Usuario, con las propiedades; Nombre, contraseña.

En el ViewModel creo la propiedad full Usuarios en una observable `collection`, aquí heredo el `bindablebase` con su `InotifyPropertyChange`

En el `view` hago `Binding` en dos `TextBox`; Usuario.nombre y Usuario.contraseña.

Pero no se notifica el cambio al escribir en los `textbox`.

¿Donde tengo que notificar los cambios en el Model ó en el `VisualModel`?

¿Cómo debería hacer esto correctamente?

Este es el código

Model

```
public class UsuarioModel
{
    public string Nombre{get;set;}
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
    public DelegateCommand MouseLeftButtonDown { get;private set; }
    public DelegateCommand Salir { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand Login { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand PasswordChanged {get;set;}

    private UsuarioModel _usuario;          
    public UsuarioModel Usuario
    {
        get { return _usuario; }
        set {SetProperty(ref _usuario, value); }
    }

    public LoginVM()
    {
        MouseLeftButtonDown = new        DelegateCommand(MouseLeftButtonDownExecute,MouseLeftButtonDownCanExecute);
        Salir = new DelegateCommand(SalirExecute, SalirCanExecute);
        Login = new DelegateCommand(LoginExecute, LoginCanExecute);
        PasswordChanged = new DelegateCommand(PasswordChangedExecute, PasswordChangedCanExecute);
        Usuario = new UsuarioModel();
    }
```

View

```
    <Label Content="Usuario:" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground= "#FFFF5254" Margin="15,0,0,0"></Label>
            <Border  Grid.Row="1" Margin="15,0,15,0" Background="#FFDCD4D4" CornerRadius="10">
                <TextBox  Background="#FFDCD4D4" Margin="10,0,10,0" FontSize="15" Foreground="#FFA82020" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="1" BorderThickness="0" Text="{Binding Usuario.Nombre,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Border>
            <Label Content="Contraseña:" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFF5254" Margin="15,0,0,0"></Label>
            <Border Grid.Row="3" Background="#FFDCD4D4" Margin="15,0,15,0" CornerRadius="10">
                <PasswordBox  Margin="10,0,10,0" Background="#FFDCD4D4"    FontSize="15" Foreground="#FFA82020" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="2" BorderThickness="0">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PasswordChanged">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding PasswordChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtPassword}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </PasswordBox>
            </Border>
```

Comment: Entiendo que en el viewmodel defines una lista ObservableColection con los usuario, pero despues representas estos en textbox, como puede reflejar una lista en textbox, salvo que sea uno a la vez,pero como defines la instancia del elemento de a lista que se asigna el textbox?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Leandro. Te explico: Como comenté soy nuevo en este patrón y también programando. Creo el modelo usuario y este lo instancio en el view model desde donde hago el bind en el view, es para un login solo necesito un user realmente la colección solo tiene un usuario.

Comment: el codigo que has implementado lo veo correcto, esta ahora te actualiza las propiedades de la entidad que bindeas a los textbox?

Comment: Si escribo en el textbox el nombre me aparece bien, pero si lo escribo en la propiedad, no me actualiza el texbox. con lo que interpreto que está fallando algo.

Comment: edite la respuesta agregando lo que entiendo faltaria para reflejar el cambio cuando asignas la propiedad

Comment: No brindes una respuesta para "agradecer" el esfuerzo de otros usuarios. Si una respuesta te ayudó para resolver tu problema, márcala como [aceptada](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227) (para más información, lee el enlace)

Answer (score 2):

Deberias evaluar si tienes el `Mode = TwoWay` asignado al binding de los textbox

[WPF - Data Binding](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm)

como observaras en el articulo hace uso de Binding

```
<TextBox Name = "nameText" Grid.Column = "1" Margin = "2" 
     Text = "{Binding Name, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
```

**>>Donde tengo que notificar los cambios en el Model o en el VisualModel?**

Deberias hacerlo en la propiedad que es actualizada lanzando la notificacion sobre la propia entidad

El tema es que en tu caso quizas la entidad esta separada de las demas que deberias recibir la notificacion.
La pregunta seria necesitas notificar que la propiedad cambio? porque por la descripcion que realizas no lo veo necesario.

**>>Si escribo en el textbox el nombre me aparece bien, pero si lo escribo en la propiedad, no me actualiza el texbox.**

En el Set de la propiedad, por ejemplo Nombre de UsuarioModel debes lanzar el NotifyPropertyChange para que el textbox se entere del cambio y lo refleje en pantalla

[Cómo: Implementar la interfaz INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

. Crea una vista (ventana, user control, etc) - carpeta views
. Crea una clase base, en este caso "Usuario" - carpeta models
. Crea una clase que será ViewModel 'UsuarioViewModel' - carpeta viewmodels

. En 'UsuarioViewModel' crea un objeto 'Usuario' COMO PROPERTY, sigue esta nomenclatura

```
private Usuario _usuarioActual;
public Usuario UsuarioActual
{
    get { return _usuarioActual; }
    set
    {
        _usuarioActual = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UsuarioActual"));
    }
}
```

. Si trabajas con una lista de usuarios agregala como ObservableCollection

```
private ObservableCollection<Usuario> _listaUsuarios;
public ObservableCollection<Usuario> ListaUsuarios = new ObservableCollection<Usuario>();
{
    get { return _listaUsuarios; }
    set
    {
        _listaUsuarios = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListaUsuarios"));
    }
}
```

. Fíjate que en los SET puedes controlar el cambio de valor luego de que se asigna y hacer cosas con ellos, por ejemplo

```
set
{       
    if(value.Edad < 18)
    {
        DenegarAcceso();
    }
    else    
    {
    _usuarioActual = value;
    if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UsuarioActual"));
    }
}
```

. Para evitar problemas siempre inicializa las colecciones directamente.
. Los click de los botones se manejan con ICommands, pero eso es para un post más largo..

Ve a la vista, en este caso una ventana, y referencia el ViewModel

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>                        
        <!-- ViewModels -->
        <vm:MyViewModel x:Key="MyVM" />
    </ResourceDictionary> 
</Window.Resources>
```

. Al grid principal puedes asignarle el DataContext o si habrá más de un ViewModel involucrado lo asignas donde corresponda.

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MyVM}">
...
</Grid>
```

Luego en los botones no les das eventos, le asignas un 'Command', puedes agregarle un parámetro al Command, por ejemplo acá le asigno un command que está en el ViewModel y además envio el botón mismo como parámetro

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Si no le asignas el DataContext a toda la vista, pero este botón si está conectado al ViewModel se lo agregas

```
<Button DataContext="{StaticResource MyVM}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

. Agrega un listbox y le asignas la lista de usuarios que está en el ViewModel

```
<ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ListaUsuarios}" SelectedItem="{Binding UsuarioActual, Mode='TwoWay'}" />
```

. Con  Mode='TwoWay' le dices que los cambios serán en ambos sentidos, desde la UI al ViewModel y viceversa. Úsa el mode twoway siempre que requieras eso. Tambien puedes agregar una propiedad de tipo int en el viewmodel par Bindearla al 'SelectedIndex' del listbox

```
SelectedItem="{Binding IndiceActual}"
```

Todos los métodos los pones en el ViewModel o en el Model dependiendo de donde pertenezcan.

Si necesitas obtener acceso al Model desde el CodeBehind de la vista (no deberías pero porsiacaso) lo puedes hacer creando un objeto del mismo tipo como PROPERTY en el code behind y luego en el constructor asignarle como valor la dirección de memoria del ViewModel que ya está inicializado en la vista (en xaml)

```
private AppLogViewModel _myVM;
public AppLogViewModel MyVM
{
     get { return _myVM; }
     set { _myVM= value; }
}

MyVM= (MyViewModel)FindResource("MyVM");
```

. Si vas a necesitar usar el ViewModel en varias vistas es mejor no referenciarlas cada vez en cadsa vista porque eso creará una nueva instancia del ViewMode, mejor declararlo en las etiquetas XAML de la clase App.xaml

Esa es toda la ayuda que puedo ofrecerte por ahora para develar un poco el tema del patrón MVVM y el NotifyPropertyChanged, el truco es declarar el evento en cada objeto para que sus cambios se transmitan hasta la interfaz.

Lo de los Commands lo dejo pendiente.
Un saludo.